# need a little help with w3c and a form validation

Tags: forms, w3c

I get this message with a w3c validator:

```
line 112 column 30 - Fout: end tag for element "form" which is not open
```

Does anyone know why I get this message?

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" />

Uw naam:<br />

<input type="text" name="name" size="25" /><br /><br />
  Uw e-mail adres:<br />
<input type="text" name="email" size="25" /><br /><br />
  De naam van uw kennis of vriend:<br />
<input type="text" name="fename" size="25" /><br /><br />
  Het e-mail adres van uw vriend of kennis:<br />
<input name="femail" type="text" size="25" /><br /><br />
  Optional Message:<br />
<textarea rows="5" name="recon" cols="45"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Aanbevelen!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a self-closing form opening tag.  Change:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" />
```

to

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
```

Comment: When I do that, it throws a lot of other errors like:
line 94 column 77 - Fout: document type does not allow element "br" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag

Comment: fixed the problem. I needed to inclose all the form attributes within <p> and </p> tags